# Error about the version of GLIBC_2.33: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: linux, glibc

I am actually using a nix environment in a university cluster to compute my stuff.

When I launch my program, An error occurred saying that:
./jointinv: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /nix/store/4lha231m66mhdrp7dggmiljkdv328gh2-gfortran-9.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)

So the libc.so.6 was called by the libstdc++.so.6 and needs version 2.33.

I checked the setting of my libc in the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ with strings libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC command and I found that it does only reach the version of 2.30

I want to update this library, but since I use a university cluster and have no access to sudo stuff.

So what could I do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try and download it to your `$HOME`, the point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to it. Or try compiling in the environment where you are actually running the program.

Comment: @Robert Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to a different version of `libc.so.6` _does not work_, for reasons explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617

Comment: @Robert I did try to download it to my  $HOME but the installation seems to be failed like each time I add the path I have always a segemantation error. Add an other path does not work(nix/store/XXXXXXXXX-glibc-2.33-lib/lib for exemple), It reports me an error of 'lookup', only private version of glibc is found.